# Can the sum of all rationals under a number be finite?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, rational-numbers

Does there exist any non zero number x such that the sum of all rationals between 0 and x is finite?

Comment: What are your thoughts? Please provide some context for the question

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 4):

WLOG, assume $x > 0$. Note that there are infinitely many $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $\frac1n \in [0, x).$ Note that $\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac1n = \infty$. Conclude.

---

Edit: Technically all I've stated above is not sufficient. You need to use the fact that there exists $N_0 \in \Bbb N$ such that $\frac1n \in [0, x)$ for all $n > N_0$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use the density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$ to show that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists infinitely many rationals in $[\frac \varepsilon 2, \varepsilon]$, and conclude.